# Regex for 12hr and 24hr time format

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I am using two regex for validating time in 12hr and 24hr format,but in some cases it is not working.Am i doing something wrong in these regex?It is not working

For validating 12 hr format like 10:00 AM/12:00 PM i have used regex

```
^(([0]?[0-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9][ ][aApP][mM])|((1[3-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9])$
```

For validating 24 hr format like 23:00/12:00 i have used regex

```
^(([0]?[0-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9])|((1[3-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9])$
```

Comment: point out some cases that your regexes don't work with? Have you tried some regex-tool like Expresso to check your regexes?

Comment: The format of the regular expression depends on the application. You write perl-regular expressions. These won't work with emacs. Search the web. There you find many pre-built regular expressions, e.g.: http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=4&categoryId=5&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1 .

Comment: i think u can use js here rather than validation.try to look at this demo:http://keith-wood.name/timeEntry.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have some of the 24 hr format in your first regex. The 12 hr format alone could be simplified to this:

```
new Regex(@"^(?:0?[0-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9] [ap]m$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

And for the 24 hr format, you can simplify it to:

```
new Regex(@"^(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$");
```

Or to combine both:

```
new Regex(@"^(?:(?:0?[0-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9] [ap]m|(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9])$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: +1, but you don't need `IgnoreCase` in the 24h regex, and you might or might not want to make the `[01]` optional.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Thanks, that's me for copy/pasting lines xD